# custom permalink pattern in laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes

I've been trying to build CMS, i'm getting confused how or what pattern should i use to make pretty **Permalink** for front-end side and which is the fastest way to load/call page with data based on type of page like blogs, category, tags, products,etc, also which is the good approach performance wise ?

Also maintaining high level of security, and google standards keeping in mind so that it won't be consider as spam or anything....simply just approved by google adsense.

I tried based on URL segment,

```
    //In Routes:
    //Route::group(['namespace' => 'Front'], function(){
    //       Route::get('/',"Main@index")->name('allPages'); 
    //   });

    public function index()
    {
       protected $layout = 'frontPages.';
       $param1 = request()->segment(1); // URL parameter one
       $param2 = request()->segment(2); // URL parameter two
       if (empty($param1)) {
        return view($this->layout . 'index');
       }
       if (!empty($param2) && !empty($param3)) {
          if($param2 === 'blog'){
            return view($this->layout . 'blogs');
         }
       }
    }
```

or based on Route Filters provided by laravel ?

```
Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');

Route::get('blog/{id}', function($id)
{
    // Only called if {id} is numeric.
});
```

or query based or ?

or HTACCESS based ?

Comment: just read https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, but assuming you want advise on how to manage your url structure etc, I would say the `Route` option is by far the best, since it has a sophisticated way of filtering/selecting and keeps an easy-to-read overview for you to reference in your code. And as @Aleksandrs said, have a look at all the possibilities Laravel routing gives you.